# Gerund vs infinitive: He lay in bed planning (to plan) the days to come

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm confused about gerund and infinitive in this sentence. Please understand me.

> He lay in bed planning (to plan) the days to come.

In that sentence, planning is correct. But I think "to plan" is correct.

I'm waiting for your answer. Thanks

Comment: There is no rush to accept an answer - even mine! https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He lay in bed to plan the days to come.

The presence of **to** in this context makes me think that he stayed in bed **in order to** plan the days to come.  Planning was his reason to stay in bed.

> He lay in bed, planning the days to come.

I take this to mean that he was planning the days to come, and he happened to be in bed while he was doing it. It is not known why he stayed in bed.

Unless you want to make it clear that he deliberately stayed in bed in order to plan, the gerund form is probably the better choice.